# Can a loosely connected PSU damage a laptop?

Tags: laptop, power-supply, battery, power, voltage

is it a bad thing that the cable connects to the power adapter block in a laptop power supply comes loose and is left alone while the laptop is under use (as shown in the picture)? I am worried it could damage my hardware components due to unstable voltage.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The part of the connector you have circled doesn't often loosen or fail. The connector is relatively strong there. It is also easy to replace the cable that goes from the wall to the brick. You should do this, and if the issues continue when after replacing that part, you should replace the brick as well.